# How to delete phpMyAdmin database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

How to delete phpMyAdmin database?
I tried few ways but it can't delete database.

1)There are no drop button at server_databases page.

2)Using DROP DATABASE database_name; but error.

MySQL said:
"DROP DATABASE" statements are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin two method provided,

localhost,

```
 1.Query Statement:
               DROP DATABASE Datebasename;

2.button  method:
```

[drop database touch to remove database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Lfb.png)

localhost restart then again it.

liveserver side,

```
           cannot do that it.
```